# How to do grouping (by category) of other apps in Android launcher home-screen using my app

Tags: android, firebase, android-launcher

I have a launcher that does not allow to create folders and I want to have an application that will allow applications grouping and keep a clean home screen.

The application to look into [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android) to get its instructions.
I want to be able to have multiple groupings (group by categories) re-using the same application if possible and if not, easily create multiple instances of the same application.